# Snowflake How to execute remove file in stage through a stored procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to execute `rm @mystage/data/input/ pattern='.*success.*';` from a stored proc

I'm getting an error message `"Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'UNKNOWN'."`

Comment: Please be specific.  What exactly are you trying to do when you get the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure works for me

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RM_FROM_STAGE() RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
$$ snowflake.execute({sqlText: `rm @mystage/test/ pattern='.*success.*'` }); $$;
```

Maybe all you need are the backquotes...

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the solution did not work here is the error message: Execution error in store procedure RM_FROM_STAGE: Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'UNKNOWN'. At Snowflake.execute, line 3 position 14

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RM_FROM_STAGE() 
returns string
    language javascript
    strict
    execute as owner
    as 
    $$

    snowflake.execute({sqlText: `rm @mystage/test/ pattern='.*success.*'` }); 

    $$
    ;

Comment: If it works with EXECUTE AS OWNER but not CALLER then it is an access (GRANT) issue.  STRICT has no meaning when there are no parameters.